# Why does the rvalue parameter change to lvalue when used?

Tags: c++

I pass rvalue `std::move(x)` to `testForward(T&& v)`, but it calls `print(T& t)` inside.

It seems that the rvalue `v` has changed to an lvalue before it calls `print()`. I do not know why this happened.  Can anyone explain it?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
void print(T& t) {
    std::cout << "Lvalue ref" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void print(T&& t) {
    std::cout << "Rvalue ref" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void testForward(T&& v) {
    print(v); // call print(T& t);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x = 1;
    testForward(std::move(x)); // output: Lvalue ref
}
```

Comment: `print(v);` since `v` has a name (which is... `v`), it's an lvalue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of the expression `v` is an lvalue, because:

> ... Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression

If you want to *forward* a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) as its original category, use [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward), ie,

```
template<typename T>
void testForward(T&& v) {
    print(std::forward<T>(v));
}
```

Comment: Just a side note: In *given* case even `std::move` should be fine as for l-value references there's already an explicit overload, so this one should only get called on true r-value references. Still `std::forward` produces the same result anyway – and as the more general solution (correct even if the other overload doesn't exist) it should be the preferred one.

Comment: Agreed, but I don't want to recommend using `std::move` with forwarding references when it'll probably confuse someone later.

Comment: Don't want to either (-> *'preferred one'*), just intended for completeness…

Comment: it means even if the `v` is a right value reference type, but when it  should be treated as lvalues when it passes to a function since it has name.  am i right?

Comment: It's probably clearer to use the technical terms (rvalue) than to translate them back into their notional original meaning (right value), since they've diverged significantly from where they started. And yes, the issue is that any expression consisting of a variable name is an lvalue, whatever the category of the underlying variable.